# Mailing Google Sheet as CSV

Tags: csv, google-sheets, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

Just trying to take the current spreadsheet tab and mail it to an address as a *.csv file.  I've gone through a huge number of prior questions but haven't found an answer.  This is adapted from a successful send of a PDF file.  The only issue is that I need CSV instead of PDF.

```
function mailCSV() {
// Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
// Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
// Send the CSV of the spreadsheet to this email address
   var email_send_address = "email@emailsample.com"; 
   var email_subject ='subject'
// Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var url = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+ ss + "&exportFormat=csv"; 

//var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs('application/csv').getBytes();
//var attachCSV = {fileName: email_subject,content:url,mimeType:'application/csv'};

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var attachments = [{fileName:"dg_request.csv", content: res.getContent(),mimeType:"application/vnd.csv"}];

MailApp.sendEmail(email_send_address, email_subject, {attachments: attachments});

// MailApp.sendEmail(email_send_address, email_subject, {attachments:[attachCSV]});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better answer which sends as an attachment:

Full credit to: https://gist.github.com/nirajkadam/0b41a01b8e739800c964

```
function mailRequestCSV() {

// Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
var recipients = "someone@somewhere.com"; 
var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var subject = "DataGenerationRequest ";
var body = "****NOTE: THIS IS AN AUTO COMPUTER-GENERATED REPORT****";
var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?format=csvx&id="+ssID;
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);
var contents = result.getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".csv", content:contents, mimeType:"application//csv"}]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay a bunch of mucking around and I finally stumbled onto a solution which is simple and simply works. (Shows you that even a blind pig can find an ear of corn).  Note that it does not send a file but rather actually sends the csv as the body of the message... which is fine for my purposes.

```
function mailRequestCSV() {

// Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email_send_address = "david.fickes@sunrunhome.com"; 
  var email_subject = "datagen request"

// Get the currently active spreadsheet ID
  var fileID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Build the URL 
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key='+fileID+'&output=csv';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_send_address, email_subject, response);
}
```

Comment: Now the only question is can I get it as an attachment formatted as csv.  The above works but as an attachment, I end up with a bunch of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Attempted in Jan 2022 and it wasn't working for me.

**My solution was to simply change the URL format** to:

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SpreadSheetId + "/export?format=csv&gid=" + SheetId;
```

Where

```
SpeadSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
SheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Name of your sheet").getSheetId();
```